# Is there a thermal sensor with a distance of 10 meters for Arduino

Tags: sensors

I am looking for a thermal sensor with a distance of 10 meters . In my plan , I would like to recognize objects based on the heat. for example car.

Comment: Check this one i just found. http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1675620.pdf . Price is friendly ~36 pounds. This is other datasheet http://www.mouser.com/pdfdocs/D6T01_ThermalIRSensorWhitepaper.pdf

Comment: @Martynas I can't find  maximum distance in datasheet.

Comment: Because there is no distance. You get a matrix. Here look at this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_ix0Rd4pIeA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [this one](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/9570) at £20?

The range depends on what lens you put in front of it - this has to be plastic as IR doesn't penetrate glass, but you can set your own range, like a focus adjustment. Commercial IR remote thermometers generally have aiming dots (laser) so you can see the optimum range - there's a fixed lens.

The actual sensor won't have a defined range, because of this.